# Add responsive card view bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to add card view using bootstrap html,css.
[image]

I am trying to do exact like the above image but unable to do. Here is my code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cardview">
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="numbers">94%</div>
            <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
        </div>                
    </div>       
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="numbers">193</div>
            <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="numbers">13%</div>
            <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
        </div>                
    </div> 
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="numbers">24.5</div>
            <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
        </div>                
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="numbers">13%</div>
            <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
        </div>                
    </div> 
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="numbers">24.5</div>
            <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
        </div>                
    </div> 
</div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
          <div class="card">
              <div>
                  <div class="numbers">94%</div>
                  <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
              </div>                
          </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
          <div class="card">
              <div>
                  <div class="numbers">193</div>
                  <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
              </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
          <div class="card">
              <div>
                  <div class="numbers">13%</div>
                  <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
              </div>                
          </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
          <div class="card">
              <div>
                  <div class="numbers">24.5</div>
                  <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
              </div>                
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 p-2">
      <div class="card h-100">
          <div>
              <div class="numbers">13%</div>
              <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 p-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="numbers">24.5</div>
            <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
        </div>                
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 p-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="numbers">24.5</div>
            <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
        </div>                
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 p-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="numbers">24.5</div>
            <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
        </div>                
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 p-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="numbers">24.5</div>
            <div class="percentage">6% since last year</div>
        </div>                
    </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this [Bootstrap card view generator](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/tools/builders/cards/) to create your cards!

Comment: I have multiple card view. So how to add space between all cards?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.codeply.com/go/29IGJHkqVd) will help you out more!, i think thats what you are trying to achieve